# In swift how do I see if a specific character is present in a UITextField?

Tags: swift

Firstly, apologies - new to all this.

I am trying to take whatever text a user has inputted to a UITextField and see if it contains a certain letter, then count the number of times that letter has been entered.

So for example, if the string was "Hello" I would want it to return, as a score if like, that there are two l's. I don't want it to be case sensitive.

Thanks!

Comment: You should try something your own first !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this extension:

```
extension String
{
    func numberOfChars(char:Character) -> Int
    {
        var counter = 0
        for chr in self
        {
            if chr == char
            {
                counter++
            }
        }
        return counter
    }
}
```

**And then use it like:**

```
println(textField.text.numberOfChars(Character("a")))
```

Answer (score 0):

To check when the user has entered text in your UITextField you can use: `addObserver` to the UITextField and create a method using `observeValueForKeyPath`. In this method you can use to count the number of characters:

```
let someString = "Hello"
let count = Array(someString).map { $0 == "l" }.filter { $0 == true }.count
```

To use an extension like Dejan Skledar suggested:

```
extension String {
    func numberOfChars(char: Character) -> Int {
        return Array(someString).map { $0 == "l" }.filter { $0 == true }.count
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
println(textField.text.numberOfChars("l") // prints "3"
```